# How determine what web-page is opening using chm-file

Tags: javascript, browser, detect, chm

How determine what web-page is opening using chm-file?
I want to deny access to a web page using the any "normal" browser.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't.

HTML Help Viewer (hh.exe) uses an embedded Internet Explorer, so it acts like a browser as well.